# I can feel the electricity on my pc case

Tags: desktop-computer, ups, electric-shock, ground, esd

I have a pc that is connected to a UPS and connected to the outlet. When I turn on the UPS while holding the pc case I can feel a small electric shock, also when the UPS is on charging mode I can feel the electricity all over the case. I know it's not normal to feel the electricity on the case, do I have a faulty PSU, a faulty UPS or its normal?

Comment: Do you feel the shock if you connect the PC directly to a wall socket (and not the UPS)?

Comment: Does your country have earthed power sockets? It your PC power connector plug 2 or 3 pin?

Comment: no i did not feel any shock, i can only feel it when the UPS is on charging mode. it is connected to a 3 pin plug

Comment: This is normal actually for non-grounded electrics. The more wattage is being used, the more electricity builds up if it can't leak towards ground, and thus the more you can feel it. If your UPS is connected to a grounded socket and that grounded socket works, then it could be a faulty ups.

Comment: "It is connected to a 3 pin plug"  <-- If the plug is grounded there should not be any presence of electricity on the case. I have a grounded UPS downstairs and the case is completely inert.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is not connected to a grounded walloutlet, it is very normal to feel the electricity, given that ground cannot be leaked into ground.

In many houses, the computer is not put into a grounded wall-outlet. It will not kill your pc, but if you put it in a grounded wall-outlet, a pc will usually run slightly more stable. It is recommended, but not a requirement.

If your UPS is connected to a grounded wall-outlet, and that outlet is also working properly (the ground pin is connected to the ground powerline that runs in the house), then the UPS or one of its cables is likely faulty, as that shouldn't happen.